# How to create a enum using > :none

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a enum like this:

`enum status: { none: 0, standard: 1, advanced: 2 }`

But it creates error with

> ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "Customer", but this will generate a class method "none", which is already defined by Active Record.

So Is there any way to create a enum with this `:none`? Thanks!

Comment: It's like asking if you can define a method with a name that is a keyword. Even if you could, it would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, nope. But you might use a suffix or a prefix. Like

```
enum status: { none: 0, standard: 1, advanced: 2 }, _suffix: true
```

And use it like

```
object.none_status
```